# google-php-spreadsheet-api was return not all data from sheet

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

If in sheet has row with all empty cell. Example:

```
   cell1     cell2
row1 : not empty not empty
row2 : not empty not empty
row3 : empty     empty
row4 : not empty not empty
row5 : not empty not empty
```

Google returned data like:

```
   cell1     cell2
row1 : not empty not empty
row2 : not empty not empty
```

How get all data with empty cell to. I using [php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client/blob/master/README.md) . My code:

```
....

$tokenArray = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
$accessToken = $tokenArray["access_token"];

$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);
$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();

$tokenArray = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
$accessToken = $tokenArray["access_token"];

$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle('MySpreadsheet');
$worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
$worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle('Sheet 1');
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();
foreach ($listFeed->getEntries() as $entry) {
    $values = $entry->getValues();
    $array [] = $values;
}
```

Comment: No,  i use  method  for get csv

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called '*return-empty'* which is set to false by default hence only returning cells that aren't empty in the feed. Set this to 'true' in your cell query and you will be able to update the value of empty cell.

You may use the  [Official Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?csw=1#which_version_of_the_api_should_be_used) for your reference. Documentation includes sample codes.

Comment: Thanks,  but I found nothing